# Side effect of only binding current property of a ref

Tags: reactjs

In https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated the sample code is using the following construct.

```
const App = () => {

  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  ....
}
```

I have never seen the current value of a ref being bound to a variable directly while *discarding* the reference to the created ref immediately.

If we only care about accessing and setting a ref value and do not pass it around, is it valid to write it like this or would not having a handle to the actual ref object result in some strange side effects like it being garbage collected and recreated on every render?

Comment: Are you using ReactJS or React Native? (You have tagged with JS, but linked the Native docs)

Comment: I am using both, but the behavior of refs should be uniform to both platforms so react should be a good place to ask.  I just stumbled upon it on some react native related docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only drawback is that if you do it like this, you lose the ability to change this ref to anything else.
Example without current:

```
const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));
fadeAnim.current = new Animated.Value(1);
```

Example with current:

```
const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
// won't work
fadeAnim = new Animated.Value(1);
```